How to prove that events A and B are the same as C and D (A=C, B=D) in two different systems if their spacetime intervals are equal?
Consider two spacetime intervals that are equal in two different intertial systems 1 and 2: $$s_1^2=s_2^2$$
Let events A and B happen in system 1 and have coordinates: $$A(T_a,X_a,Y_a,Z_a)$$ $$B(T_b,X_b,Y_b,Z_b)$$
$$s_1^2=c^2(T_b-T_a)^2-(X_b-X_a)^2-(Y_b-Y_a)^2-(Z_b-Z_a)^2$$
Let events C and D happen in system 2 and have coordinates: $$C(T_c,X_c,Y_c,Z_c)$$ $$D(T_d,X_d,Y_d,Z_d)$$
$$s_2^2=c^2(T_d-T_c)^2-(X_d-X_c)^2-(Y_d-Y_c)^2-(Z_d-Z_c)^2$$
We know that $s_1^2=s_2^2$
How to prove that events A and B are the same as C and D (A=C, B=D) in two different systems if their spacetime intervals are equal?
Thanks.

What does "happen in system 1" mean?

It is exactly three miles from my house to Home Depot.  It is also exactly three miles from my house to Chucky Cheese's.  Are you suggesting that therefore there is no difference between Home Depot and Chucky Cheese's?

In general the mere fact that two events have the same spacetime interval between them doesn't mean they are the same event. For example, if there is a wall one metre to my left and another wall one metre to my right, then some events on wall 1 may have the same spacetime interval from me as those on wall 2 but they're not the same events, so the premise of your question is false.
If you take two events A, B and describe them in a different coordinate systems they will have different coordinates, but in special relativity they will have the same spacetime interval between them in both coordinate systems as calculated using the equation for the interval in your question. There are various ways of motivating and explaining this that can be found in many textbooks, e.g. - "Gravity" by James B. Hartle.


How to prove that events A and B are the same as C and D in two different systems

"Are the same" is ambiguous. However, in this context, that can only mean that the spaces use the same measuring units and their intervals are identical.
Modulo that; yes,  A and B must be the same as C and D.

Yes it is legitimate. I didn't downvote. Read WillO's comment and alanf's answer. The distance between two points don't generally specify the two points. Think about normal 3D space.
